# How can I set the "lifecycle" option for my project?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I am currently in the process of learning Swift as a beginner and I am using Xcode 14.2 for my learning journey.

In the tutorial book I am following, it mentions the ability to configure the "lifecycle" within UIKit App Delegate.

However, I have encountered a challenge in locating this particular option when I attempt to initiate a new project.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could kindly guide me on how to properly set up the "lifecycle" for a project within the context of my current Xcode version.

Alternatively, I wonder if it is unnecessary to perform this step anymore due to the advancements in Xcode versions 12 and above.

Thank you ever so much for your time and assistance.

[image: Create project - step 1]
[image: Create project - step 2]

Tried:
Try to find "lifecycle" option in "General" tab of project.
[image]

Expecting:
Understand how to set "lifecycle" within UIKit App Delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the life cycle setting for creating a new project is deprecated in the latest Xcode. That's why you don't see it in your Xcode.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695644

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 12** introduced the "Life Cycle" options "UIKit / AppKit AppDelegate" and "SwiftUI" when creating a new project.

**Xcode 13** and later do not have this option anymore. The setting is inferred from the "Interface" setting, i.e. if you need an AppDelegate life cycle, choose "Storyboard".

**Solution**: When creating a new iOS project in XCode 13 and above, select „Storyboard“ to get a „UIKit App Delegate“ life cycle.